# Resize an image to fill a picture box without stretching

Tags: c#, picturebox

I was wanting to get an image to fill a picture box, but not leaving any whitespace. Thus cutting off parts of the image to fit when its not resized to the aspect ratio of the pictureBox. And to adjust as the user resizes the window/pictureBox. The existing options, `Sizemode = Zoom` leaves whitespace, as its afraid to cut off any of the image and `Sizemode = StretchImage` stretches the image, distorting it.

The only way I can think of doing this is creating an algorithm to resize the image, keeping the contrast ratio, and setting the width or length of the image to the pictureBox width or length and creating some runtime loop which runs the algorithm once a frame. It seems kind of performance heavy for what it does and kind of hackish. Is there a better option?

Edit:
For anyone coming by, I implemented Ivan Stoev's solution slightly differently:

```
class ImageHandling
{
    public static Rectangle GetScaledRectangle(Image img, Rectangle thumbRect)
    {
        Size sourceSize = img.Size;
        Size targetSize = thumbRect.Size;
        float scale = Math.Max((float) targetSize.Width / sourceSize.Width, (float) targetSize.Height / sourceSize.Height);
        var rect = new RectangleF();
        rect.Width = scale * sourceSize.Width;
        rect.Height = scale * sourceSize.Height;
        rect.X = (targetSize.Width - rect.Width) / 2;
        rect.Y = (targetSize.Height - rect.Height) / 2;
        return Rectangle.Round(rect);
    }

    public static Image GetResizedImage(Image img, Rectangle rect)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image) b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height);
        g.Dispose();
        try
        {
            return (Image)b.Clone();
        }
        finally
        {
            b.Dispose();
            b = null;
            g = null;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        updateMainBackground();
    }

    void updateMainBackground()
    {
        Image img = Properties.Resources.BackgroundMain;
        Rectangle newRect = ImageHandling.GetScaledRectangle(img, mainBackground.ClientRectangle);
        mainBackground.Image = ImageHandling.GetResizedImage(img, newRect);
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateMainBackground();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are seeking for a "Fill" mode (similar to Windows background picture). There is no standard way of doing that, but it's not so hard to make your own with the help of a small calculation and GDI+:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    public class ImageFillBox : Control
    {
        public ImageFillBox()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, false);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.Opaque | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        }
        private Image image;
        public Image Image
        {
            get { return image; }
            set
            {
                if (image == value) return;
                image = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            if (image == null)
                e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);
            else
            {
                Size sourceSize = image.Size, targetSize = ClientSize;
                float scale = Math.Max((float)targetSize.Width / sourceSize.Width, (float)targetSize.Height / sourceSize.Height);
                var rect = new RectangleF();
                rect.Width = scale * sourceSize.Width;
                rect.Height = scale * sourceSize.Height;
                rect.X = (targetSize.Width - rect.Width) / 2;
                rect.Y = (targetSize.Height - rect.Height) / 2;
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, rect);
            }
        }
    }
    static class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var testForm = new Form();
            testForm.Controls.Add(new ImageFillBox
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                Image = GetImage(@"http://www.celebrityrockstarguitars.com/rock/images/Metall_1.jpg")
            });
            Application.Run(testForm);
        }
        static Image GetImage(string path)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(path);
            if (uri.IsFile) return Image.FromFile(path);
            using (var client = new WebClient())
                return Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(uri)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the PictureBoxSizeMode documentation you can specify PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom to get the image to keep its aspect ratio. It will zoom as big as possible without any part of the image overflowing the picture box.

And you can play with the Dock property (setting DockStyle.Full) to get the picture box to resize to the size of its container.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly simple solution to this. `PictureBox.SizeMode` has a few settings that will help us out. Zoom will adjust the image to fit in the box and Normal will place the picture with out resizing. What we will want to do is check the height and width of the image and if it is larger than the `PictureBox` size we will Zoom, if not, we will place it in with Normal. See below:

```
if (image.Height > pctbx_ImageRecognition.Height || image.Width > pctbx_ImageRecognition.Width)
    pctbx_ImageRecognition.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
else
    pctbx_ImageRecognition.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that only fixes the size of the imagebox and this code works better for that:


                if (image.Height > imageBox.Height || image.Width > imageBox.Width)
                    imageBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                else
                    imageBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;